# how to free draw Circle and Rectangle using Fabric js using mouse?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric js to draw move resize rectangles.
But one thing that I am getting stuck is to be able to draw circle or rectangle on mouse drag i.e. free drawing. 
I am following this tutorial example
[a line drawing example](http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/)!
But it did not explain about how to draw rectangle or circle like this example.

I am a beginner in using Fabric js , please help me out.

Code : `//Declaring the variables
        var isMouseDown=false;
        var OriginX=new Array();
        var OriginY= new Array();
        var refRect;

```
    //Setting the mouse events
    canvas1.on('mouse:down',function(event){
        //Defining the procedure
        isMouseDown=true;
        OriginX=[];
        OriginY=[];

        //Getting yhe mouse Co-ordinates
        var posX=event.e.clientX;
        var posY=event.e.clientY;
        OriginX.push(posX);
        OriginY.push(posY);

        //Creating the rectangle object
        var rect=new fabric.Rect({
            left:OriginX[0],
            top:OriginY[0],
            width:0,
            height:0,
            stroke:'red',
            strokeWidth:3,
            fill:''
        });
        canvas1.add(rect);

        refRect=rect;  //**Reference of rectangle object

    });

    canvas1.on('mouse:move', function(event){
        // Defining the procedure

        if(!isMouseDown)
        {
            return;
        }
        //Getting yhe mouse Co-ordinates
        var posX=event.e.clientX;
        var posY=event.e.clientY;

        refRect.setWidth(Math.abs((posX-refRect.get('left'))));
        refRect.setHeight(Math.abs((posY-refRect.get('top'))));
        canvas1.renderAll();


    });

    canvas1.on('mouse:up',function(){
        //alert("mouse up!");
        isMouseDown=false;
    });`
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code example of your attempt and what did not work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I dont really know how to write the code for that as I am a newbie to fabric js. But you can see the code for line drawing @http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/

Comment: Please paste the code you are trying here and please avoid links.

Comment: I am really sorry , but I am unable to add code here . I am getting errors which I am not able to figure out. Could you please go to http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/ and click "Cancel drawing mode" , In the right hand side , you will see the code. If you are good with stackoverflow, please suggest me edits by adding code.

Comment: What is the error you are getting or issue you are facing? the code that you have copied from or using may be slight different from the one which you have referred. There are changes for modification intentionally or by mistake. Please share the code that you have tried which would help other users easy to understand your problem  and to provide better solutions. You can simply copy your code and paste it on a text editor and apply a tab/4 spaces to each line then copy and paste it on the stack overflow editor.

Comment: I have finally added some code . please let me know why the mouse positions aren't coming correctly.

Comment: Draw Rectangle Anwer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417603/fabric-js-free-draw-a-rectangle/45917491#45917491

Comment: Draw Circle Answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111045/how-to-free-draw-circle-using-fabric-js/46268027#46268027

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417603/fabric-js-free-draw-a-rectangle