# How to free draw circle using Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using *FabricJS*  to draw circle in canvas:

```
var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 100,
                 fill: '',
                 stroke: 'red',
                 strokeWidth: 3,
                 originX: 'center', 
                 originY: 'center' 
               });
            var text = new fabric.Text('HELLO WORLD.',
                        {  fontSize: 30, 
                            originX: 'center', 
                            originY: 'center',
                            fill : 'red' 
                          });
            var group = new fabric.Group([ circle, text ], { 
                                           left: 150, top: 100
                                         });
            canvas.add(group);
```

This code draws a normal circle but I need to freely draw circle with mouse.
Any code help will be appreciated.

Comment: Certainly, there is a jump from drawing a static shape to drawing something based on user input. This question comes off as, "I don't know what to do next, so will someone do this next [big] step for me." Instead, I suggest hitting up Google, and doing some more research or tutorials before hitting up StackOverflow for answers like this, as-is, you probably won't get answers from this question.

Comment: To help you get on your way, I suggest that you begin to consider the user-interaction for drawing your shape. The two most common ways to draw circles are: first-click indicates the center, and the second click indicates the radius from the first-click. Alternatively, two clicks can indicate the top-left-bottom-right bounding box for the circle.

Comment: Okay I have done something for rectangle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/8u1cqasa/2/ can we do something for Circle in a similar way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your previous code for drawing rectangle http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/8u1cqasa/2/ **Here is the code for drawing circle:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Getting the canvas
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas("canvas2");
var freeDrawing = true;
var divPos = {};
var offset = $("#canvas2").offset();
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    divPos = {
        left: e.pageX - offset.left,
        top: e.pageY - offset.top
    };
});
$('#2').click(function(){       

    //Declaring the variables
    var isMouseDown=false;
    var refCircle;

    //Setting the mouse events
    canvas1.on('mouse:down',function(event){           
        isMouseDown=true;            
        if(freeDrawing) {
        var circle=new fabric.Circle({
            left:divPos.left,
            top:divPos.top,                
            radius:0,
            stroke:'red',
            strokeWidth:3,
            fill:''
        });
        canvas1.add(circle);
        refCircle=circle;  //**Reference of rectangle object
       }

    });

    canvas1.on('mouse:move', function(event){
        if(!isMouseDown)
        {
            return;
        }
        //Getting yhe mouse Co-ordinates
        if(freeDrawing) {
            var posX=divPos.left;
            var posY=divPos.top;    
            refCircle.set('radius',Math.abs((posX-refCircle.get('left'))));            
            canvas1.renderAll(); 
        }
    });

    canvas1.on('mouse:up',function(){
        canvas1.add(refCircle);
        //alert("mouse up!");
        isMouseDown=false;
        //freeDrawing=false;  // **Disables line drawing
    });
 });
 });
```

Comment: It works , but if I drag to left or top, it still draws in right. So, its a bit buggy. Can you check that?

Answer (score 5):

```js
var Circle = (function() {
  function Circle(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.className = 'Circle';
    this.isDrawing = false;
    this.bindEvents();
  }

  Circle.prototype.bindEvents = function() {
    var inst = this;
    inst.canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
      inst.onMouseDown(o);
    });
    inst.canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
      inst.onMouseMove(o);
    });
    inst.canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
      inst.onMouseUp(o);
    });
    inst.canvas.on('object:moving', function(o) {
      inst.disable();
    })
  }

  Circle.prototype.onMouseUp = function(o) {
    var inst = this;
    inst.disable();
  };

  Circle.prototype.onMouseMove = function(o) {
    var inst = this;
    if (!inst.isEnable()) {
      return;
    }

    var pointer = inst.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    var activeObj = inst.canvas.getActiveObject();

    activeObj.stroke = 'red',
      activeObj.strokeWidth = 5;
    activeObj.fill = 'red';

    if (origX > pointer.x) {
      activeObj.set({
        left: Math.abs(pointer.x)
      });
    }

    if (origY > pointer.y) {
      activeObj.set({
        top: Math.abs(pointer.y)
      });
    }

    activeObj.set({
      rx: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x) / 2
    });
    activeObj.set({
      ry: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y) / 2
    });
    activeObj.setCoords();
    inst.canvas.renderAll();
  };

  Circle.prototype.onMouseDown = function(o) {
    var inst = this;
    inst.enable();

    var pointer = inst.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;

    var ellipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
      top: origY,
      left: origX,
      rx: 0,
      ry: 0,
      transparentCorners: false,
      hasBorders: false,
      hasControls: false
    });

    inst.canvas.add(ellipse).setActiveObject(ellipse);
  };

  Circle.prototype.isEnable = function() {
    return this.isDrawing;
  }

  Circle.prototype.enable = function() {
    this.isDrawing = true;
  }

  Circle.prototype.disable = function() {
    this.isDrawing = false;
  }

  return Circle;
}());




var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var circle = new Circle(canvas);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js"></script>
 Please draw circle here

<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: solid 1px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is the detail blog with jsfiddle - https://blog.thirdrocktechkno.com/sketching-circle-of-a-html5-canvas-using-the-fabricjs-f7dbfa20cf2d

Comment: You should unregister the event listeners when on mouseup - if not drawing several circles could bring chaos. Also, check out my free rectangle drawing implementation which doesn't use DOM apis like e.clientX, offsetLeft, etc to track the coords, but fabric.js APIs only which I think is safer - now working on build the circle editor looking at your work. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of drawing a rectangle which I carefully made and works for latest versions. Krunan example seems to work OK- just in case this is a rectangle free drawing implementation that doesn't use DOM apis like e.clientX, offsetLeft, etc to track the coords, but fabric.js APIs only which I think is safer. Also unregister event listeners - I'm still trying to refine it since I need free drawing support for my project - Since there is no official support for this I wanted to reference the example here for others.

https://cancerberosgx.github.io/demos/misc/fabricRectangleFreeDrawing.html

Answer (score -4):

An easy way to add a Circle to a canvas:

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: "green", top: 100, left: 100 }));
```